# Try Everywhere but not getting satisfactory answer about SearchView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-searchmanager

This is my OnCreateOptionMenu 
 An error is showing in setOnQueryListener 
  here contact_object is model class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

 {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_list,menu);
    final MenuItem myMenuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search_contact);
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem (R.id.search_contact) .getActionView ();
    changedSearchViewTextColor(searchView);
   // ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

              if (!searchView.isIconified()){
                searchView.setIconified(true);
            }
            myMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            return false;
        }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
             newText=newText.toLowerCase();
            final List<Contact_Object> filtermodelist=filter(contacts,newText);
            adapter.setFilter(filtermodelist);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
  }
```

I have implemented the filter option as below

```
    public List<Contact_Object> filter(List<Contact_Object> p,String query ) 
    {
    query=query.toLowerCase();
    final List<Contact_Object> filterModeList=new ArrayList<>();
    for (Contact_Object model :p){
        final String text=model.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (text.startsWith(query)){
            filterModeList.add(model);

        }
    }
    return filterModeList;
}
```

I have declared the setFilter function as follow in CustomAdapter class

```
     public  void  setFilter(List<Contact_Object> listItem){
    parentList=new ArrayList<>();
    parentList.addAll(listItem);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have tried  hard but didn't get the appropriate answer 
please anyone help me,waiting for answer

Comment: What `error`? Provide exception from logicat.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Your `SearchView` is `null` check how did you connect `SearchView` with `Id` seems you messed something up there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no logic in `onQueryTextChange` because `newText` is not passed anywhere. You are passing the `empty` list to the `setFilter` method.

```
 @Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    newText = newText.toLowerCase();
    final List<Contact_Object> filterModeList=new ArrayList<>();
    for (Contact_Object obj : p) {
        String name = obj.getName().toLowerCase();
        if(name.contains(newText))
            filterModeList.add(obj);
    }
    adapter.setFilter(filtermodelist);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: final List<Contact_Object> 
                 filtermodelist=filter(contacts,newText);